# is it possible to change the controls in Lego Digital Designer?

Tags: ldd

I am wondering if it is possible to change the controls in LEGO Digital designer? Because I would like to change the "D" button on my keyboard to "rotate to the right" instead of "delete".

And I'm also having a little issue. I found a guy on the internet that's adding new parts to LEGO Digital designer but the only problem is my program is crashing sometimes when I load a baseplate that the guy added to the program. Is there a fix for the crashing? I think it is crashing because maybe it is too much for the program to handle.

Comment: I've edited your question a little, but it turns out you got TWO questions/issues here. It would be better if you stick to one issue per question. You can edit this question with other details relevant to your "button" issue and raise a new question for your "crashing LDD".

Comment: As a general piece of advice, AutoHotkey is able to remap virtually any key to any other one - regardless of the user application.